# Azure Databricks : The backend could not get session tokens for path /mnt. Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?

Tags: azure, databricks, aws-databricks, spark-bash-azure-databricks

I'm trying to Mount Azure Blob storage containers to DBFS. Implementation is as below.
got below following error . Not sure why I'm getting an error  ***Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?***  when I'm trying to connect to azure blob storage.

Do I missing anything here? Could you please help me solving this issue - Thanks --

**Code Implementation**

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/iotdata",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")})
```

**Error**

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o275.mount.
: com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException: The backend could not get session tokens for path /mnt. Did you remove the AWS key for the mount point?
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.common.InvalidMountException$.apply(DataMessages.scala:612)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.filesystem.MountEntryResolver.resolve(MountEntryResolver.scala:84)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed below steps to successfully mount and read data in dataframe from Azure blob storage.

**Step1:** Import pyspark and SparkSession

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

[image]

**Step2:** Use below command to unmount any existing mount point

```
dbutils.fs.unmount("/mnt")
```

[image]

**Step3:** To get key of storage

Go to storage account and select Access keys

[image]

Now click on Show keys as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Then copy first key.

[image]

**Step4:** To mount blob storage use below code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "wasbs://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  mount_point = "/mnt/Sales",
  extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net": "key"})
```

[image]

From your given code you must remove  `dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")` and replace it with Azure blob storage key only.

**Step5:**  Read data in dataframe from blob storage container

[image]

**Step6:** Dataframe

[image]

**Step7:** Original CSV file in blob storage

[image]

Comment: it didn't work for me. Are there any permissions I need to look into before mounting?
or any extra permissions i need to give on the access key or scope ??

Comment: No, there are no permissions needed. Steps given in above answer are enough. I have updated my answer to show where you can get key of storage account.